# Carousel of cards

Tags: jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

I don't know how to name my problem, so I'm sorry about the title.

I made this section with some cards, but I want to make something like a menu, I don't know how to call it...it's like, I put arrows pointed right and left and when I click on it, more cards appear. I think it's like a carousel. But until now I couldn't make what I want.
Like this image:

[image]

```
<section id="tres">
        <h1> TEST </h1>
    <hr>

    <div id="cards02">

    <div class="card" style="width: 25rem;" id="card-1">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="idosa.png" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">TEST
</h4>
   <h6> 13 Outubro 2017</h6>
    <p class="card-text">TEST TEST TEST  </p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">TEST </a>
  </div>
</div>




    <div class="card" style="width: 25rem;" id="card-2">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="idosa.png" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">TEST TEST TEST 
</h4>
   <h6> 13 Outubro 2017</h6>
    <p class="card-text">TEST TEST TEST </p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">TEST </a>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 25rem;" id="card-3">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="idosa.png" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title"TEST TEST TEST 
</h4>
   <h6> 13 Outubro 2017</h6>
    <p class="card-text">TEST </p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">TEST</a>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>  

    </section>
```

Comment: hey please provide full code with  css ,html and js

Comment: here: https://pastebin.com/UuSWWuHu

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is exactly a carousel, just so you know you will have to use more than pure html (more specific JS and css if needed), if you don't want to know the details of creating a carousel you can always use libraries like **bootstrap** (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) or **slick** (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). But if you want to create one you will have to look for a tutorial (which there are many around the web "carousel js css tutorial") because its a long process.

Comment: Link only answers and recommendations for third-party software are not allowed on SO. This question is off topic anyway and shouldn't be answered. Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...
    ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem.
    ...solicit opinions rather than facts ...make no attempt to write the code or ask to write the code for them." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla JS carousel you can look at, it slides on its own and stops sliding if the user clicks the arrows for manual control. If you wanted multiple elements to show rather than just one, you could just do some minor tweaking to this.

```js
//Changed index so 1 is actually first image, rather than starting at 0 index
var index = 1;
var paused = false;
var slideShow = [];

for (i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow").length; i++) {
  slideShow[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow")[i];
  slideShow[i].style.display = "none";
}

slideShow[0].style.display = "inline";

var slides = setInterval(function() {
  if (index < slideShow.length) {
    index++;
  showDivs();
  }
  else {
  index = 1;
  showDivs();
 }
},1000);

function control(n) {
  clearInterval(slides);

  if (index+n > slideShow.length) {
    index = 1;
  }
  else if (index+n <= 0) {
    index = slideShow.length;
  }
  else {
  index += n;
  }
  showDivs();
}

function showDivs() {
  //Hide all slideShow elements, and then show only the targeted element
  for (let i=1; i<=slideShow.length; i++) {
    slideShow[i-1].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideShow[index-1].style.display = "inline";
}
```

```html
<button  onclick="control(-1)" class="arrows" id="left"><</button>
<p class="slideShow">1</p>
<p class="slideShow">2</p>
<p class="slideShow">3</p>
<p class="slideShow">4</p>
<p class="slideShow">5</p>
<button onclick="control(1)" class="arrows" id="right">></button>
```